# Fill missing dates of an array automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a table in google sheet with these columns Date Credit Debit and Balance I have entries a few days a month only but I want to see the balance chart for all days, so that I know when it is stable
how do you think I can do that?
Here is the workbook [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xx6zM-QTqg2-VgVBMdPWagR1Qjaox-0xRt-yqm9D6lA/edit#gid=0)

nothing is coming to my mind so far, I was wondering if I can use appscripts or formulas for this because it's not sensible to list the dates and everything manually especially when the dataset is very big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a couple of additional columns. With this formula you can create an array of all the dates included in the range, and with XLOOKUP it finds the value of that date (or the previous one, if it doesn't appear):

```
=LET(end,MAX(A3:A),
start,MIN(FILTER(A3:A,A3:A<>"")),
dates,SEQUENCE(end-start,1,start),
BYROW(dates,LAMBDA(each,HSTACK(each,XLOOKUP(each,A:A,F:F,,-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and effort, really appreciate it

Comment: I'm gonna study what you did